Can't figure out how to query Opensearch and have results
this is my (very simple) query:
GET /authors_development
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "vittorio",
      "fields": ["display_name"]
    }
  }
}

And this is what I have in my index:
  {
    "_index": "authors_development_20240605091139006",
    "_id": "65fd65576bb92c000d331f5d",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "author_id": {
        "$oid": "65fd65576bb92c000d331f5d"
      },
      "display_name": "Vittorio",
      "system": false,
      "entries_usernames": [
        "Vittorio"
      ]
    }
  }

What am I doing wrong? It returns something that looks statistics, and not the actual results...

Hey Nicholas, the query looks good it's expected to see normal results like in your index. Can you share what it returns?

what happens is that it doesn't match because "vittorio" is different from "Vittorio" (capital). I'm very confused :) Return 0 hits and a bunch of stats

Check the field mapping. If display_name field saved as text and it uses standard analyzer it should match.
GET authors_development/_mapping/field/display_name

I assume that you are searching like GET authors_development/_search
